PHP, bloqueo en servidor al enviar muchos correos
Tengo una aplicación que envía correos de varias listas, pero tengo varias limitantes.
Si quiero enviar correos masivos, digamos unos 140, lo reparto en bloques de 70 y mando un sleep a mi código de 60 segundos para continuar.
Pero ahí viene el otro problema, el servidor tiene un tiempo límite de ejecución y me manda una respuesta ...Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in...
En un promedió, en cada intento los correos enviados son 33.
Estoy pensando que alternativas tengo un PHP para poder hacer ese envió masivo de correos.
Lo primero que me vino a la mente son hilos, pero no sé si estos solucionen el problema o si sean factibles de programar en php.
Otro cosa que pense es usar algo similar a un ajax pero en su versión php para redireccionar la información y poder continuar, pero lo único que conozco que podría hacer esto es header y no sé si pueda enviar una variable que marque donde me quedé en el nuevo php.
Es decir, enviar los email límite en el primer php y al tener faltantes usar un header que abra el mismo archivo con una variable, digamos el id del registro donde me quede y continuar de nuevo desde ahí. De esta forma hasta terminar con todos los correos.

Podrias relanzar ese script via cron supongo, anotando en alguna parte en que punto quedó la última ejecución

Hola, si no me equívoco el cron es para programar tareas, pero lo que quiero es enviarlos de forma seguída de forma prefeente. Igualmente la idea del cron es una opción, no sé si se pueda crear desde php o se deban crear desde el server, por qué no tengo acceso a este ademas del espacio donde subo los archivos de la aplicación.

Normalmente, si el panel del usuario del hosting lo permite, te ofrecen agregar trabajos al cron del servidor ejecutados desde tu cuenta de usuario. El mínimo de tiempo que puedes establecer para un trabajo cron en ejecutarse de nuevo es de un minuto. Los PHP que se ejecutan desde el cron tienen que tener en cuenta algunos pequeños detalles para ejecutarse, pero son igualmente válidos. Si te lo montas bien, puedes ejecutar tu script cada minuto en el servidor y actuar o no en consecuencia para enviar los emails que haya pendientes o no.  Es una idea, hazlo como quieras o te dejen.

hay un ejemplo en el repo de PHPMailer con ponerle un LIMIT 25 al select, debería ir tomando y enviando de a poco. un meta refresh o cron o ajax sobre eso debería ser trivial

Hola Fernando, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganes otra medalla. Con respecto a tu pregunta, pensa que TODO tiene un límite. No podes agendar miles mails, la cola de salida del servidor de mail se llenaría. No podes enviar miles de mails a un dominio, todos tienen una quota por minuto y/o hora. En otras palabras, para evitar problemas, tenes que hacer envíos segmentados, por lotes, en intervalos de tiempo razonables.

Independientemente del funcionamiento del código, debes considerar que si envías correos masivos desde un correo, ese correo terminará en una lista negra y la mayoría de mensajes de un futuro código exitoso terminaran en la carpeta spam de los destinatarios. Para enviar correos masivos debes pensar en otra alternativa, como listas de distribución tipo Mail Chimp (gratuito hasta 2,000 destinatarios) o Google Groups, donde mandarías un solo correo, al email del grupo, y ese email llega a todos los miembros del grupo.
